# git - see branches introduced between two commits?

Tags: git

Is there a way to see which branches were introduced between two commits? Before deploying my code I'd like to be able to compute which branches were merged into master since the last release commit.

Comment: *Is there a way [...]?* Yes and no. Branch references are meant to move along the commit graph over time, and Git doesn't remember where branches were on the graph (except in the reflog). Your best bet is to inspect your merge commits and look for `Merge 'branch so-and-so'` in their commit messages.

Comment: You could start with something like `git log --all --merges oldrelease..newrelease`. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, though. But it should show you all commits with more than one parent that are included in `newrelease` but not in `oldrelease`... And the `--all` should follow all parents of each of those so you can see branches that were merged into other branches that were eventually merged into your mainline...